# Angular button keeps re-rendering repeatedly

Tags: angular

My Angular button keeps re-rendering repeatedly, I think its linked to the way I handle the application of my *[ngClass]*, as per the comment in [Multiple conditions in ngClass - Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44821875/multiple-conditions-in-ngclass-angular-4#comment109913822_47666882).

**HTML**

```
<button
  [ngClass]="getCourseContentButtonClass(button.uid, button.title)"
></button>
```

**Component**

```
  isCourseContentButtonPrimary(title: string) {
    return CourseContentService.IsCourseContentButtonPrimary(title);
  }

  isCourseContentElementSelected(uid: string) {
    return this.selectedCourseElementUid === uid;
  }

  getCourseContentButtonClass(uid: string, title: string) {
    let courseContentButton;
    if (CourseContentService.IsCourseContentButtonPrimary(title)) {
      courseContentButton = 'btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-3 course-content-button ';
    } else {
      courseContentButton = 'btn btn-sm btn-primary-soft mr-3 course-content-button ';
    }
    if (this.isCourseContentElementSelected(uid)) {
      courseContentButton += ' course-content-button-active';
    }
    return courseContentButton;
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by rerendering repeatedly? Does it crash ?

Comment: As in there is a slight animation flicker when it transitions between state.

Comment: re-rendering suggest change detection is firing. have you confirmed that it's the class. i.e. if you remove [ngClass] from the element. does it still render continuously?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57060232/angular-performance-ngstyle-recalculates-on-each-click-on-random-input) might help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like you may have an [infinite circular event loop](https://www.mattspaulding.org/The-Curious-Case-of-Angular-and-the-Infinite-Change-Event-Loop/) on the button, because have a method in your binding, which maybe invoked for every change detection between a parent child relationship. From the names I am assuming Course Content is a parent of Course element, you may want to break that cycle [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49914732/6085193) explains something similar